# Task-level authentication challenge to URLSession: which exact method of delegate will be called

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, ios10

When it comes to task-level authentication of a `URLSession` I see references to two different method signatures in Apple's documentation:

- E.g. [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiontaskdelegate) is a reference to `urlSession(_,task:,didReceive:, completionHandler:)`.
- E.g. [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1) is a reference to `urlSession(_, task:,didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler)`.

Which is the right one (or do both apply under different circumstances)?

Intuitively one could think that the 1st one is a typo (mistake in documentation), and that the 2nd one applies. But a look into iOS header files suggests that the 1st one applies and the 2nd is a typo or obsolete.

So which exact method of a `URLSessionDelegate` will be called (in iOS 10) for delivering a (task-level) authentication challenge to an app? (I will go with the 1st one for the time being.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the same delegate method. You just got the Swift signature wrong in your second example. See [the documentation for the method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessiontaskdelegate/1411595-urlsession) and switch between Swift and Objective-C. So the actual signature is indeed `urlSession(_, task:, didReceive:, completionHandler:)`.

Comment: Didn't get Apple the signature wrong in this case (See 2nd like to documentation)? Perhaps it is because this documentation is marked prerelease (from June 2016).

Comment: On further inspection: Maybe the signatures are slightly different between the Objective-C and Swift versions. I am interested in the Swift version for which the 1st sample indeed seems to apply.

Comment: Yes, the signatures do differ in Swift and Objective-C. No, it's not an error. In Objective-C, we need to specify _what_ was received to distinguish between several possibilities. In Swift, we [also have (reliable) type information to distinguish them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690076/multiple-functions-with-the-same-name) so there's no need to put that (redundant) information in the method name.

Comment: Okay, got it now. Thx.