# What exactly differentiate two functions in Swift?

Tags: swift, function

I wonder what makes two "similar functions" different with each other and can be called unambiguously

This is what I've learned from self-study

The uniqueness comes from: Function name + Argument order and argument name + return type. The combination of them must be unique to be able to make the function unique (Please see the example below)

1. `Nmu1` and `Num2` would cause ambiguous, because the return type (doesn't has the so called return name, the function name already act as this role) is not referred when calling a function
2. Although `Num3` function has a different parameter name, it won't uniquely separate it from the function in `Num1` and `Num2`. Because the argument name won't referred when the function had been called therefore, only a different argument name won't make a function unique; And the function in `Num4` is different with all functions above, because its signature Function name + Argument order and argument name + return type is unique among all previous 3 functions.
3. `Num5` and `Num6` functions are different with each other, for they have different argument orders when they were defined

   ```
   //Num1
   func foo(guy name: String) -> String {
        return "Hi \(name)"
   }

   //Num2
   func foo(guy name: String) {
       print("Hi \(name)")
   }

   //Num3
   func foo(guy called: String) -> String {
       return "Hi \(called)"
   }

   //Num4
   func foo(dude name: String) -> String {
       return "What's up \(name)"
   }

   //Num5
   func foo(man name: String, from place: String) {
      print("Hi! I'm \(name) I come from \(place)")
   }

   //Num6
   func foo(from place: String, man name: String) {
      print("Hi! I'm \(name) I come from \(place)")
   }
   ```

**Question**: I might miss or possibly even misunderstood some parts. It would be very nice of you that you can correct me and add the parts I missed

Thanks

[Update]
Let's discuss a bit more on this issue. Let's started with the question that discuss [the difference between Argument and Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter). This question makes a lot of sense here!

Back to the quote from the official swift document

> Each function parameter has both an argument label and a parameter name. The argument label is used when calling the function; each argument is written in the function call with its argument label before it. The parameter name is used in the implementation of the function. By default, parameters use their parameter name as their argument label.

Argument, Parameter, Argument Labels and Parameter Names are different. The difference here can be used to differential functions.

**Functions with same parameter name, same parameter order, same return type and even same function body can be differentiated from different argument Labels.**

```
func foo(dude name: String) -> Int {
    print("Hi \(name)!")
    return 1
}

func foo(man name: String) -> Int {
    print("Hi \(name)!")
    return 1
}

//foo(dude: String) & foo(man: String) is identical when calling
```

For more information please address to [Multiple functions with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690076/multiple-functions-with-the-same-name)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690076/multiple-functions-with-the-same-name.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks so much. It helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defined as Obj-C- compatible methods, Num1 and Num2 can not exist together, and you will have error defining them in `NSObject` subclass; however, you can mark them as `@nonobjc` and error will gone, since Swift able to choose correct overload by return type expected:

```
//Num1
@nonobjc func foo(guy name: String) -> String {
     return "Hi \(name)"
}

//Num2
@nonobjc func foo(guy name: String) {
    print("Hi \(name)")
}
```

All your other points, except this mark, seems correct to me